# Error while building cobalt. ccache error starboard-toolchains

Tags: cobalt

I am currently at step **#2** in `Build and Run Cobalt` at https://cobalt.dev/development/setup-linux.html#build-and-run-cobalt.

Here is the log

```
aivan@DESKTOP-G1SFK1K:~/Development/PL/cobalt$ python cobalt/build/gn.py -p linux-x64x11
gn gen out/linux-x64x11_devel
Build Accelerator: ccache
Build Accelerator: ccache
Done. Made 738 targets from 291 files in 334ms
aivan@DESKTOP-G1SFK1K:~/Development/PL/cobalt$ ninja -C out/linux-x64x11_devel all
ninja: Entering directory `out/linux-x64x11_devel'
[27/15550] CXX obj/base/base_static/base_switches.o
FAILED: obj/base/base_static/base_switches.o
ccache "../../../../../starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/clang++" -MMD -MF obj/base/base_static/base_switches.o.d -DSTARBOARD_BUILD_TYPE_DEVEL -DCOBALT_BUILD_TYPE_DEVEL -D_DEBUG -DCOBALT_LOGGING_ENABLED -DDIAL_SERVER -DSTARBOARD -DCOBALT -DSB_GN_GL_TYPE_IS_NONE=0 -DENABLE_DEBUGGER -DENABLE_DEBUG_COMMAND_LINE_SWITCHES -DENABLE_TEST_RUNNER -DENABLE_IGNORE_CERTIFICATE_ERRORS -DSB_ABORT_ON_ALLOCATION_FAILURE -DSTARBOARD_ALLOWS_MEMORY_TRACKING -DSB_IS_EVERGREEN_COMPATIBLE=1 -DSB_IS_EVERGREEN_COMPATIBLE_LIBUNWIND=1 -DSTARBOARD_ATOMIC_INCLUDE=\"starboard/linux/x64x11/atomic_public.h\" -DSTARBOARD_CONFIGURATION_INCLUDE=\"starboard/linux/x64x11/configuration_public.h\" -DSB_SABI_JSON_ID=R\"\(\{\"alignment_char\":1,\"alignment_double\":8,\"alignment_float\":4,\"alignment_int\":4,\"alignment_llong\":8,\"alignment_long\":8,\"alignment_pointer\":8,\"alignment_short\":2,\"calling_convention\":\"sysv\",\"endianness\":\"little\",\"floating_point_abi\":\"\",\"floating_point_fpu\":\"\",\"sb_api_version\":15,\"signedness_of_char\":\"signed\",\"signedness_of_enum\":\"signed\",\"size_of_char\":1,\"size_of_double\":8,\"size_of_enum\":4,\"size_of_float\":4,\"size_of_int\":4,\"size_of_llong\":8,\"size_of_long\":8,\"size_of_pointer\":8,\"size_of_short\":2,\"target_arch\":\"x64\",\"target_arch_sub\":\"\",\"word_size\":64\}\)\" -DSB_API_VERSION=15 -DSB_SABI_TARGET_ARCH=\"x64\" -DSB_SABI_WORD_SIZE=\"64\" -DSB_IS_ARCH_X64=1 -DSB_HAS_SYSV_CALLING=1 -DSB_HAS__FLOATS=1 -DSB_IS_64_BIT=1 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_CHAR=1 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_DOUBLE=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_FLOAT=4 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_INT=4 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_LLONG=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_LONG=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_POINTER=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_SHORT=2 -DSB_SIZE_OF_CHAR=1 -DSB_SIZE_OF_ENUM=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_DOUBLE=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_FLOAT=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_INT=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_LONG=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_LLONG=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_POINTER=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_SHORT=2 -DSB_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DSB_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DSB_HAS_SIGNED_CHAR=1 -DSB_HAS_SIGNED_ENUM=1 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DCOBALT_LINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_LIBCPP_DEBUG=0 -DMESA_EGL_NO_X11_HEADERS -DADDRESS_SANITIZER -DASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=\"/home/aivan/starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/llvm-symbolizer\" -I../.. -Igen -O2 -O2 -Werror -fcolor-diagnostics -fvisibility=hidden -Wconversion -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-deprecated -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-sign-conversion -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-local-typedef -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-implicit-exception-spec-mismatch -Wno-unused-parameter -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wno-undefined-bool-conversion -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-conversion -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-bitfield-width -Wno-undefined-var-template -fno-exceptions -frtti -std=gnu++14 -c ../../base/base_switches.cc -o obj/base/base_static/base_switches.o
ccache: error: execv of ../../../../../starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/clang++ failed: No such file or directory
[33/15550] CC obj/base/third_party/dynamic_annotations/dynamic_annotations/dynamic_annotations.o
FAILED: obj/base/third_party/dynamic_annotations/dynamic_annotations/dynamic_annotations.o
ccache "../../../../../starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/clang" -MMD -MF obj/base/third_party/dynamic_annotations/dynamic_annotations/dynamic_annotations.o.d -DSTARBOARD_BUILD_TYPE_DEVEL -DCOBALT_BUILD_TYPE_DEVEL -D_DEBUG -DCOBALT_LOGGING_ENABLED -DDIAL_SERVER -DSTARBOARD -DCOBALT -DSB_GN_GL_TYPE_IS_NONE=0 -DENABLE_DEBUGGER -DENABLE_DEBUG_COMMAND_LINE_SWITCHES -DENABLE_TEST_RUNNER -DENABLE_IGNORE_CERTIFICATE_ERRORS -DSB_ABORT_ON_ALLOCATION_FAILURE -DSTARBOARD_ALLOWS_MEMORY_TRACKING -DSB_IS_EVERGREEN_COMPATIBLE=1 -DSB_IS_EVERGREEN_COMPATIBLE_LIBUNWIND=1 -DSTARBOARD_ATOMIC_INCLUDE=\"starboard/linux/x64x11/atomic_public.h\" -DSTARBOARD_CONFIGURATION_INCLUDE=\"starboard/linux/x64x11/configuration_public.h\" -DSB_SABI_JSON_ID=R\"\(\{\"alignment_char\":1,\"alignment_double\":8,\"alignment_float\":4,\"alignment_int\":4,\"alignment_llong\":8,\"alignment_long\":8,\"alignment_pointer\":8,\"alignment_short\":2,\"calling_convention\":\"sysv\",\"endianness\":\"little\",\"floating_point_abi\":\"\",\"floating_point_fpu\":\"\",\"sb_api_version\":15,\"signedness_of_char\":\"signed\",\"signedness_of_enum\":\"signed\",\"size_of_char\":1,\"size_of_double\":8,\"size_of_enum\":4,\"size_of_float\":4,\"size_of_int\":4,\"size_of_llong\":8,\"size_of_long\":8,\"size_of_pointer\":8,\"size_of_short\":2,\"target_arch\":\"x64\",\"target_arch_sub\":\"\",\"word_size\":64\}\)\" -DSB_API_VERSION=15 -DSB_SABI_TARGET_ARCH=\"x64\" -DSB_SABI_WORD_SIZE=\"64\" -DSB_IS_ARCH_X64=1 -DSB_HAS_SYSV_CALLING=1 -DSB_HAS__FLOATS=1 -DSB_IS_64_BIT=1 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_CHAR=1 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_DOUBLE=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_FLOAT=4 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_INT=4 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_LLONG=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_LONG=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_POINTER=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_SHORT=2 -DSB_SIZE_OF_CHAR=1 -DSB_SIZE_OF_ENUM=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_DOUBLE=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_FLOAT=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_INT=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_LONG=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_LLONG=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_POINTER=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_SHORT=2 -DSB_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DSB_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DSB_HAS_SIGNED_CHAR=1 -DSB_HAS_SIGNED_ENUM=1 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DCOBALT_LINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_LIBCPP_DEBUG=0 -DMESA_EGL_NO_X11_HEADERS -DADDRESS_SANITIZER -DASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=\"/home/aivan/starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/llvm-symbolizer\" -I../.. -Igen -Os -O2 -Werror -fcolor-diagnostics -fvisibility=hidden -Wconversion -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-deprecated -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-sign-conversion -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-local-typedef -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-implicit-exception-spec-mismatch -Wno-unused-parameter -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wno-undefined-bool-conversion -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-conversion -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-bitfield-width -Wno-undefined-var-template -std=c99 -c ../../base/third_party/dynamic_annotations/dynamic_annotations.c -o obj/base/third_party/dynamic_annotations/dynamic_annotations/dynamic_annotations.o
ccache: error: execv of ../../../../../starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/clang failed: No such file or directory
[34/15550] CXX obj/build/config/sanitizers/options_sources/sanitizer_options.o
FAILED: obj/build/config/sanitizers/options_sources/sanitizer_options.o
ccache "../../../../../starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/clang++" -MMD -MF obj/build/config/sanitizers/options_sources/sanitizer_options.o.d -DSTARBOARD_BUILD_TYPE_DEVEL -DCOBALT_BUILD_TYPE_DEVEL -D_DEBUG -DCOBALT_LOGGING_ENABLED -DDIAL_SERVER -DSTARBOARD -DCOBALT -DSB_GN_GL_TYPE_IS_NONE=0 -DENABLE_DEBUGGER -DENABLE_DEBUG_COMMAND_LINE_SWITCHES -DENABLE_TEST_RUNNER -DENABLE_IGNORE_CERTIFICATE_ERRORS -DSB_ABORT_ON_ALLOCATION_FAILURE -DSTARBOARD_ALLOWS_MEMORY_TRACKING -DSB_IS_EVERGREEN_COMPATIBLE=1 -DSB_IS_EVERGREEN_COMPATIBLE_LIBUNWIND=1 -DSTARBOARD_ATOMIC_INCLUDE=\"starboard/linux/x64x11/atomic_public.h\" -DSTARBOARD_CONFIGURATION_INCLUDE=\"starboard/linux/x64x11/configuration_public.h\" -DSB_SABI_JSON_ID=R\"\(\{\"alignment_char\":1,\"alignment_double\":8,\"alignment_float\":4,\"alignment_int\":4,\"alignment_llong\":8,\"alignment_long\":8,\"alignment_pointer\":8,\"alignment_short\":2,\"calling_convention\":\"sysv\",\"endianness\":\"little\",\"floating_point_abi\":\"\",\"floating_point_fpu\":\"\",\"sb_api_version\":15,\"signedness_of_char\":\"signed\",\"signedness_of_enum\":\"signed\",\"size_of_char\":1,\"size_of_double\":8,\"size_of_enum\":4,\"size_of_float\":4,\"size_of_int\":4,\"size_of_llong\":8,\"size_of_long\":8,\"size_of_pointer\":8,\"size_of_short\":2,\"target_arch\":\"x64\",\"target_arch_sub\":\"\",\"word_size\":64\}\)\" -DSB_API_VERSION=15 -DSB_SABI_TARGET_ARCH=\"x64\" -DSB_SABI_WORD_SIZE=\"64\" -DSB_IS_ARCH_X64=1 -DSB_HAS_SYSV_CALLING=1 -DSB_HAS__FLOATS=1 -DSB_IS_64_BIT=1 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_CHAR=1 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_DOUBLE=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_FLOAT=4 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_INT=4 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_LLONG=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_LONG=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_POINTER=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_SHORT=2 -DSB_SIZE_OF_CHAR=1 -DSB_SIZE_OF_ENUM=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_DOUBLE=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_FLOAT=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_INT=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_LONG=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_LLONG=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_POINTER=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_SHORT=2 -DSB_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DSB_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DSB_HAS_SIGNED_CHAR=1 -DSB_HAS_SIGNED_ENUM=1 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DCOBALT_LINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_LIBCPP_DEBUG=0 -DMESA_EGL_NO_X11_HEADERS -DADDRESS_SANITIZER -DASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=\"/home/aivan/starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/llvm-symbolizer\" -I../.. -Igen -Os -O2 -Werror -fcolor-diagnostics -fvisibility=hidden -Wconversion -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-deprecated -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-sign-conversion -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-local-typedef -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-implicit-exception-spec-mismatch -Wno-unused-parameter -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wno-undefined-bool-conversion -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-conversion -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-bitfield-width -Wno-undefined-var-template -fno-exceptions -frtti -std=gnu++14 -c ../../build/sanitizers/sanitizer_options.cc -o obj/build/config/sanitizers/options_sources/sanitizer_options.o
ccache: error: execv of ../../../../../starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/clang++ failed: No such file or directory
[35/15550] CXX obj/cobalt/account/account/account_manager.o
FAILED: obj/cobalt/account/account/account_manager.o
ccache "../../../../../starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/clang++" -MMD -MF obj/cobalt/account/account/account_manager.o.d -DSTARBOARD_BUILD_TYPE_DEVEL -DCOBALT_BUILD_TYPE_DEVEL -D_DEBUG -DCOBALT_LOGGING_ENABLED -DDIAL_SERVER -DSTARBOARD -DCOBALT -DSB_GN_GL_TYPE_IS_NONE=0 -DENABLE_DEBUGGER -DENABLE_DEBUG_COMMAND_LINE_SWITCHES -DENABLE_TEST_RUNNER -DENABLE_IGNORE_CERTIFICATE_ERRORS -DSB_ABORT_ON_ALLOCATION_FAILURE -DSTARBOARD_ALLOWS_MEMORY_TRACKING -DSB_IS_EVERGREEN_COMPATIBLE=1 -DSB_IS_EVERGREEN_COMPATIBLE_LIBUNWIND=1 -DSTARBOARD_ATOMIC_INCLUDE=\"starboard/linux/x64x11/atomic_public.h\" -DSTARBOARD_CONFIGURATION_INCLUDE=\"starboard/linux/x64x11/configuration_public.h\" -DSB_SABI_JSON_ID=R\"\(\{\"alignment_char\":1,\"alignment_double\":8,\"alignment_float\":4,\"alignment_int\":4,\"alignment_llong\":8,\"alignment_long\":8,\"alignment_pointer\":8,\"alignment_short\":2,\"calling_convention\":\"sysv\",\"endianness\":\"little\",\"floating_point_abi\":\"\",\"floating_point_fpu\":\"\",\"sb_api_version\":15,\"signedness_of_char\":\"signed\",\"signedness_of_enum\":\"signed\",\"size_of_char\":1,\"size_of_double\":8,\"size_of_enum\":4,\"size_of_float\":4,\"size_of_int\":4,\"size_of_llong\":8,\"size_of_long\":8,\"size_of_pointer\":8,\"size_of_short\":2,\"target_arch\":\"x64\",\"target_arch_sub\":\"\",\"word_size\":64\}\)\" -DSB_API_VERSION=15 -DSB_SABI_TARGET_ARCH=\"x64\" -DSB_SABI_WORD_SIZE=\"64\" -DSB_IS_ARCH_X64=1 -DSB_HAS_SYSV_CALLING=1 -DSB_HAS__FLOATS=1 -DSB_IS_64_BIT=1 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_CHAR=1 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_DOUBLE=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_FLOAT=4 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_INT=4 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_LLONG=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_LONG=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_POINTER=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_SHORT=2 -DSB_SIZE_OF_CHAR=1 -DSB_SIZE_OF_ENUM=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_DOUBLE=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_FLOAT=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_INT=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_LONG=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_LLONG=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_POINTER=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_SHORT=2 -DSB_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DSB_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DSB_HAS_SIGNED_CHAR=1 -DSB_HAS_SIGNED_ENUM=1 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DCOBALT_LINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_LIBCPP_DEBUG=0 -DMESA_EGL_NO_X11_HEADERS -DADDRESS_SANITIZER -DASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=\"/home/aivan/starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/llvm-symbolizer\" -I../.. -Igen -Os -Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -O2 -Werror -fcolor-diagnostics -fvisibility=hidden -Wconversion -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-deprecated -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-sign-conversion -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-local-typedef -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-implicit-exception-spec-mismatch -Wno-unused-parameter -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-exceptions -frtti -std=gnu++14 -c ../../cobalt/account/account_manager.cc -o obj/cobalt/account/account/account_manager.o
ccache: error: execv of ../../../../../starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/clang++ failed: No such file or directory
[36/15550] CXX obj/cobalt/browser/browser_switches/switches.o
FAILED: obj/cobalt/browser/browser_switches/switches.o
ccache "../../../../../starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/clang++" -MMD -MF obj/cobalt/browser/browser_switches/switches.o.d -DSTARBOARD_BUILD_TYPE_DEVEL -DCOBALT_BUILD_TYPE_DEVEL -D_DEBUG -DCOBALT_LOGGING_ENABLED -DDIAL_SERVER -DSTARBOARD -DCOBALT -DSB_GN_GL_TYPE_IS_NONE=0 -DENABLE_DEBUGGER -DENABLE_DEBUG_COMMAND_LINE_SWITCHES -DENABLE_TEST_RUNNER -DENABLE_IGNORE_CERTIFICATE_ERRORS -DSB_ABORT_ON_ALLOCATION_FAILURE -DSTARBOARD_ALLOWS_MEMORY_TRACKING -DSB_IS_EVERGREEN_COMPATIBLE=1 -DSB_IS_EVERGREEN_COMPATIBLE_LIBUNWIND=1 -DSTARBOARD_ATOMIC_INCLUDE=\"starboard/linux/x64x11/atomic_public.h\" -DSTARBOARD_CONFIGURATION_INCLUDE=\"starboard/linux/x64x11/configuration_public.h\" -DSB_SABI_JSON_ID=R\"\(\{\"alignment_char\":1,\"alignment_double\":8,\"alignment_float\":4,\"alignment_int\":4,\"alignment_llong\":8,\"alignment_long\":8,\"alignment_pointer\":8,\"alignment_short\":2,\"calling_convention\":\"sysv\",\"endianness\":\"little\",\"floating_point_abi\":\"\",\"floating_point_fpu\":\"\",\"sb_api_version\":15,\"signedness_of_char\":\"signed\",\"signedness_of_enum\":\"signed\",\"size_of_char\":1,\"size_of_double\":8,\"size_of_enum\":4,\"size_of_float\":4,\"size_of_int\":4,\"size_of_llong\":8,\"size_of_long\":8,\"size_of_pointer\":8,\"size_of_short\":2,\"target_arch\":\"x64\",\"target_arch_sub\":\"\",\"word_size\":64\}\)\" -DSB_API_VERSION=15 -DSB_SABI_TARGET_ARCH=\"x64\" -DSB_SABI_WORD_SIZE=\"64\" -DSB_IS_ARCH_X64=1 -DSB_HAS_SYSV_CALLING=1 -DSB_HAS__FLOATS=1 -DSB_IS_64_BIT=1 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_CHAR=1 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_DOUBLE=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_FLOAT=4 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_INT=4 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_LLONG=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_LONG=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_POINTER=8 -DSB_ALIGNMENT_OF_SHORT=2 -DSB_SIZE_OF_CHAR=1 -DSB_SIZE_OF_ENUM=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_DOUBLE=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_FLOAT=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_INT=4 -DSB_SIZE_OF_LONG=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_LLONG=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_POINTER=8 -DSB_SIZE_OF_SHORT=2 -DSB_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DSB_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DSB_HAS_SIGNED_CHAR=1 -DSB_HAS_SIGNED_ENUM=1 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DCOBALT_LINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_LIBCPP_DEBUG=0 -DMESA_EGL_NO_X11_HEADERS -DADDRESS_SANITIZER -DASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=\"/home/aivan/starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/llvm-symbolizer\" -I../.. -Igen -Os -Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -O2 -Werror -fcolor-diagnostics -fvisibility=hidden -Wconversion -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-deprecated -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-sign-conversion -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-local-typedef -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-implicit-exception-spec-mismatch -Wno-unused-parameter -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-exceptions -frtti -std=gnu++14 -c ../../cobalt/browser/switches.cc -o obj/cobalt/browser/browser_switches/switches.o
ccache: error: execv of ../../../../../starboard-toolchains/x86_64-linux-gnu-clang-chromium-365097-f7e52fbd-8/bin/clang++ failed: No such file or directory
[40/15550] ACTION //cobalt/browser:cached_jinja_templates(//starboard/linux/x64x11/toolchain:target)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Anyone has idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and finally found how to solve it.

You need to execute `./starboard/tools/download_clang.sh`